# How to send parameter from a Create Form to the Action in yii2

Tags: yii2

Ok, i'm trying to make a survey tool.

So, i have a Model of the survey which reference to N questions. This is part of this model:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getIdmateria0()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Monmateria::className(), ['id' => 'idmateria']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getMonpreguntas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Monpregunta::className(), ['idencuesta' => 'id']);
}
}
```

Of course, the questions's model Monpregunta references the survey's model. Then i have a 1 to N relations between the survey and his questions.

In my ActionView i have a survey with N questions on it. Then i call a view of survey, which have a Create Form View rendered on it, in order to create the N answers of the survey.  So, once question is responded, I need to know which number of question was. I need to keep the track of which  number of questions i am responding, but for it i need to send a parameter from the form to my controller. But i do not know how to do it.

The Controller (here i need to keep the track of which questions is responded)

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    //this is my id's survey       
    $model = $this->findModel($id);        
    //here i pre create my answer 
    $modelResultado = $this->crearResultado($id);        
    //here i call the view with a Create Form embedded. When the form action it's triggered  
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelResultado'=>$modelResultado,
        'orden'=>$model->orden,
    ]);
}
//create the answer and setting the reference
protected function crearResultado($id) {
    $modelResul = new \app\models\Monresultado;
    $modelResul->idmonresultadocab = $id;
     if ($modelResul->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelResul->save()) {
        //flash
    }
    return $modelResul;
}
```

The view

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this
 * @var app\models\Monresultadocab $model
 */


?>
<div class="monresultadocab-view">


<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'idencuesta',
    ],
]) ?>
<?php
echo $this->render('_formResultado', [
    'model' => $modelResultado
  ]); ?>
</div>
```

[b]This is the _formResultado view, and here i wish to tell to the action which id's questions has been responded but i don't know how to send the parameter to the action!![/b]

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this
 * @var app\models\Monresultado $model
 * @var yii\widgets\ActiveForm $form
 */
?>

<div class="monresultado-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'idrespuesta')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Monrespuesta::find()->all(),'id','nombre'))?>           



<?= $form->field($model, 'libre')->textInput(['maxlength' => 2000]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    [b]<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Siguiente' : 'Siguiente', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>[/b]
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

If i send a parameter in the Html::submitButton tag, it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think u should pass the id of corresponding question in actionView of controller
 like:

```
   return $this->render('view', [
    'model' => $this->findModel($id), 
    ......
    ......
     ]);
```

hope it works!